# Expected value of random permutation

Tags: probability, permutations, random-variables

Let n ≥ 1 be an integer and consider a uniformly random permutation
$a_1$, $a_2$, . . . ,$a_n$ of the set {1, 2, . . . , n}. Define the random variable X to be the number of indices i for which 1 ≤ i < n and $a_i$ < $a_{i+1}$.
Determine the expected value E(X) of X. (Hint: Use indicator random variables.)

This question seems to be over my head. Any help to lead in right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** write $X$ as a sum of indicator random variables, and use the fact that they are identically distributed.

Comment: The indicator variables are not independently distributed, but then independence is *not* required to use Linearity of Expectation.  They are *identically* distributed though, and that makes the evaluation easy.

Answer (score 1):

The indicator variables could be $X_{i}$ where $X_{i}=1$ if $a_i < a_{i+1}$ and 0 otherwise.  Does $\mathbb{P}(X_{i}=1)$ depend on $i$?  Then use linearity of expectation, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(\sum X_{i})=\sum \mathbb{E}(X_{i}) = \sum \mathbb{P}(X_{i}=1)$.